# Why is chrome saving html files differently than firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

When I try to save a website I'm logged in to as an html file in chrome(as html only), when I try to open it later it wants me to log in but if I do it with firefox the page opens normally. So there must be a difference between the ways the 2 browsers save the file. Is there somewhere where I can read up more on that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why don't you do a `diff` on the two files saved from two browsers and find out yourself more about what the actual differences are...?

Comment: Why would there not be differences? HTML, CSS and Javascript can be used in many ways to achieve "the same" result.

Comment: Difference in cookie behaviour?